# Which photo montage/collage software can do this transition effect?

Tags: software, effect, software-recommendation, collage, montage

Was trying to create a photo montage and saw a nice transition effect in [Wedding montage by Alex Tan](http://vimeo.com/97935183) at time 0:39 - 0:40

I not sure what this effect was called:

```
1. a sudden exposure increase
2. transition to next image
3. sudden exposure reduce back to normal level
```

Hopefully someone can enlighten me & recommend me which light-weight software (After Effect & Premier too heavy for me) able to do this.

Am using [FotoMagico](http://boinx.com/fotomagico/) on a Mac at the moment but they do not have this effect.

Answer (score 2):

This is called "fade through white" and is available on any decent video editing software.  If not directly available, it can be emulated by any video editing software that contains keyframe animation for a brightness effect.